# Potentiometric conundrum

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry

I'm trying to develop a simple method of analysis based on the half-reaction:

$$\ce{Zn^2+(aq) + 2e- -> Zn(s)}$$

Making up the cell is a $\ce{Ag/AgCl}$ reference electrode. The cell is only $\pu{5 ml}$.

**Dress rehearsal:**

[image: ZnAgAgCl cell]

I measured the EMF of $4$ zinc sulfate stock solutions from $\pu{0.5 M}$ to $\pu{1.6E-3 M}$. Each point was replicated once. I obtained the following correlation:

[image: Potentiometry]

Using $\log_{10}$ I got a slope of:

$$\pu{8.2\pm 2.2 mV}$$

But using Nernst's Equation at $\pu{298 K}$ the value should be about $\pu{28 mV}$, **so the discrepancy is enormous!** And this means reduced sensitivity, of course.

Additional problems which may or may not be related to the first problem are:

- reproducibility wasn't great
- long equilibrium times (over $5\text{min}$)
- $\ce{ZnSO4}$ turned out of poor quality

**Does anyone know what causes the low slope problem?**

Comment: Are you using a voltmeter designed for potentiometric measurements, i.e., an electrometer? An ordinary inexpensive DMM, in voltmeter mode, has too low input impedance, by a factor of about 100,000. And reduction of hydrogen ions to hydrogen gas is also a competitor.

Comment: No, I'm using a general purpose multimeter. What instrument would you recommend instead?

Comment: Basically the kind of voltmeter used with pH electrodes is needed. They have input impedances sufficiently high to reduce current loading to around a pA. There are various high impedance voltage follower front ends that can be built relatively inexpensively and such a buffer stage would be used between the electrode and the input to a standard 10 M Ohm input impedance DMM.

Comment: OK. Where you write *And reduction of hydrogen ions to hydrogen gas is also a competitor* wouldn't that invalidate the Daniell cell?

Comment: Breakfast done, snow is only an inch, so not worth removing. The zinc metal gets oxidized, so no competition with hydrogen ion reduction. That leaves the electrometer issue. One possibility, aside from making a FET-input op amp front end for the DMM is just make a concentration cell: two solution reservoirs, a salt bridge, two zinc electrodes, zinc sulfate solution in the salt bridge and reference half-cell reservoir. That solution would be relatively concentrated and effectively constant concentration.

Comment: Yes, a concentration cell. But how would that solve the problems of low slope and long equilibration times? How does it circumvent the need for an electrometer?

Comment: You get decent currents, unlike the pA with the Ag/AgCl reference electrode. So an ordinary DMM is fine. And the Nernst equation essentially then boils down to just the indicator side, so it should work well.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your input. Will definitely try the CC.

Comment: The potential you measure at a metal electrode is not necessarily only the metal couple, but a mixed potential of all the redox reactions taking place at your electrode. If there is a significant rate of any other reactions happening at your electrode you will get a different potential. You can have for example Zn oxidation whilst having proton reduction and/or oxygen reduction.

Comment: At first glance the cell potential seem close to theory, except for the slope.

Comment: In my shed's rubble I found the remains of an old pH-meter, with console ('electrometer'). I'll see if I can breathe sole life into that...